# Specify a number literal as 8 bit?

Tags: c, gcc

```
unsigned char ascii;
int a = 0;
char string[4] = "foo"; "A1"
ascii = (string[a] - 'A' + 10) * 16;
```

> warning: conversion to ‘unsigned char’
>   from ‘int’ may alter its value

It seems that gcc considers chars and number literals as int by default. I know I could just cast the expression to (unsigned char) but how can I specify char literals and number literals as 8 bit without casts ?

A similar issue:

Literal fractions are considered double by default but they can be specified to float by:

```
3.1f
```

Therefore, 3.1 would be considered a float rather than a double.

Comment: The warning is not because of the size of your literals, but because the result of this particular expression is unlikely to fit in `unsigned char`.

Comment: @R: Not really, modifying "foo" to "A1" makes ascii 160 which is inside the 0 - 255 range. I still get the same warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `C`, you cannot do calculations in anything shorter than `int`

```
char a = '8' - '0'; /* '8' is int */
char a = (char)'8' - '0'; /* (char)'8' is converted to `int` before the subtraction */
char a = (char)'8' - (char)'0'; /* both (char)'8' and (char)'0' are converted */
```

Answer (score 2):

The C language doesn't provide any way of specifying a literal with type `char` or `unsigned char`. Use the cast.

By the way, the result of your calculation is outside the range of `unsigned char`, so the warning is quite correct - conversion will alter its value. C doesn't provide arithmetic in any type smaller than an `int`. In this case I suppose that what you want is modulo-256 arithmetic, and I think that gcc will recognise that, and will not emit the warning with the casts in place. But as far as the C language is concerned, that calculation is done in the larger type and then converted down to `unsigned char` for storage in `ascii`.

Comment: My example overflows because I used "foo" rather than a real life example. Oops!

Comment: I actually did a bit of head-scratching about that, and realised that with ASCII it still works - the difference between `f` and `F` is 32, so once multiplied by 16 the difference vanishes mod 256, and you'll get the right answer, `0xF0`. I did wonder what you were planning to do about the `o`, though ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify character literals, of type <strike>`char`</strike>`int` (`char` in C++), with specific numbers using octal or hexadecimal notation. For example, `\012` is octal 12, or decimal 10. Alternatively, you could write `'\x0a'` to mean the same thing.

However, even if you did this (and the calculation didn't overflow), it might not get rid of the warning, as the C language specifies that all operands are promoted to at least `int` (or `unsigned int`, depending on the operand types) before the calculation is done.