# Warning in g++ 4.5.2 uint16_t with Wconversion

Tags: g++

If I compile the following program with g++ and enable warnings for conversions (-Wconversion)

```
#include<stdint.h>
int main() {
  uint16_t foo = 1;
  foo += 1;
  return 0;
}
```

I get a warning,  warning: conversion to uint16_t from int may alter its value.

Fine, if the 1 in foo+=1 is interpreted as int, but what about:

```
foo+=static_cast<uint16_t>(1);
```

I get the same warning, shouldn't the operator work when the types of both sides are the same, w/o converting to an int?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got an explanation, it comes from C but this should be equally valid in C++:

[Specify a number literal as 8 bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797997/specify-a-number-literal-as-8-bit/3798099#3798099)

For arithmetic, all operands are promoted to `int` if they are smaller. This explains the problem, and why it doesn't trigger on initialization, or when casting explicitely, because the cast will be undone to calculate the sum with `int`s.

Comment: That pretty much renders the compound operators unusable (from a non-warning perspective) on "small" types.

Comment: Any operator really, every addition, multiplication or other will promote the variables to `int`.